# Can't sign in with Gmail on Pokèmon Go app

Tags: pokemon-go

I get to enter my gmail username and password, but then it takes me to "Account Help"

When I hit done on the upper left the screen freezes.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had reset my phone, reinstalled the Pokemon GO app, but I couldn't log in via google, and whenever I pressed Done, I was transferred back to the "deny or allow this app to access your bla bla bla".

If you have an iPhone using Safari as default browser, then this will probably work for you too! Here's what I did:

1. In Pokemon GO -> Sign up with google
2. Touch compass icon (bottom right)
3. Touch Allow
4. Switch to Pokemon GO app as it prompts, and it should work from there!